# Critique my PDA for this language

Tags: automata

I have attempted to create a PDA for the language $L=\{a^ib^{2i}a^i\ | \ i\geq0\}$. I have included my sketch solution below:

[image: PDA]

The basic idea is that I know there are 3 times as many characters following the first run of $a$'s (since $2i+i=3i$) so I add three times as many $a$'s as are in the first group to the stack and use them to keep count of my $b$'s and the second group of $a$'s. Does this PDA work? It should accept by final state.

Comment: What does $z_0$ mean? Is it a special character?

Comment: It's used by my textbook to denote the empty stack (some books use $ or #)

Comment: If you still want help with this I can try, but I see the question is 2 months old so maybe you've already figured it out?

Comment: @Zachary: Looks to me like you should be popping two $a$s off the stack when you read a $b$.

Comment: I already figured this one out but forgot to close the question. Thanks for the input.